# HomeKit throw Error 32, when adding a home on iOS8 simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, homekit

Code is:

```
[_homeManager addHomeWithName:@"Dave's Home" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

Error is:

> Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 32.)"

How to solve this? (I am pretty sure that the HomeKit capability is on. So is the Home Data Privacy of this application.)

Comment: I've found the reason on this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HomeKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/HMErrorCode)

Answer (score 3):

I have find reason of this error. I was found same issue in my application. This error comes when you add home of same name many times . try with "Dave's Home1" instead "Dave's Home" then it will work .
try this it works

```
[_homeManager addHomeWithName:@"Dave's Home1" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

for more information check :: https://appengineer.in/